# Count And Group By With Exclusion?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following simplified tables:

```
--- Incident ---
ID | ID_NUMBER | AREA

--- Vehicle ---
ID | NAME | INCIDENT_ID
```

How could I count the number of incidents, grouped by an area, but only if the vehicles related to an incident do not have a name like `M<any number><any number>` or `D<any number>`?

I have something like this, but the numbers seem to large:

```
select count(i.ID_NUMBER), i.AREA
from Incident i
inner join Vehicle v on v.INCIDENT_ID = i.ID
where v.NAME not like 'M[0-9][0-9]'
and v.NAME not like 'D[0-9]
group by i.AREA
```

I think the numbers are too large because it's counting each vehicle per incident, but I just want to count the number of `Incident.ID` that don't have specific 'Vehicle.NAME' involved.

To extend the example, given the following:

```
---Incident---
1 | 1234 | Here
2 | 9876 | There
3 | 4567 | Here

---Vehicle---
1 | R09 | 1234
2 | F99 | 1234
3 | Q23 | 4567
4 | Y78 | 9876
5 | M42 | 9876
```

The results would be

```
2 | Here
```

Answer (score 0):

You should count the distinct incidents and instead of a `WHERE` clause use a `HAVING` clause:

```
select count(distinct i.ID_NUMBER) counter, i.AREA
from Incident i
inner join Vehicle v on v.INCIDENT_ID = i.ID_NUMBER
group by i.AREA
having sum(case when v.NAME like 'M[0-9][0-9]' or v.NAME like 'D[0-9]' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=45a677976c707b699d54b87c070c2c01).
Results:

```
> counter | AREA
> ------: | :---
>       2 | Here
```

Comment: Hmm...all that gave me was an empty result set.

Comment: As you can see in the demo it works, but check the column names maybe I did not set them correctly because you did not include them in the sample data.

Comment: Check the edited code. The ON clause in your code was wrong and I kept it in my previous code but now it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists` instead:

```
select count(i.ID_NUMBER), i.AREA
from Incident i
where not exists (select 1
                  from vehicle v
                  where v.INCIDENT_ID = i.ID and
                        (v.NAME like 'M[0-9][0-9]' or v.NAME like 'D[0-9]')
group by i.AREA;
```

This should remove the duplicates *before* aggregation which should be a performance benefit as well.